# How do you revert flutter code migration accepted accidentally to null safety...?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can any one tell me how do you revert back the migrated code..?

I was working in `dart migrate` => Using the migration tool and accidentally clicked `Apply Migration` by thinking that migration will affect to that one active file... but now it migrated my entire project, I not ever verified all my code...

How can I revert it back...

I searched in google and stackoverflow not found any solution for it??

Comment: It's a great time to use `git`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly undo the migration.  You should use this as a lesson to use a source control system (e.g. Git, Mercurial) so that you can easily commit changes and undo them if necessary.

From this point, you either can:

- Live with the migration and fix problems that you encounter.
- Edit your `pubspec.yaml` to change the Dart SDK version requirement to `>= 2.9.0 < 3.0.0`, run `flutter analyze`/`dart analyze`, and fix all of the reported problems.  This mostly will involve:

  - Replacing all types of the form `T?` to `T`.
  - Replacing all expressions of the form `identifier!` to `identifier`.
  - Replacing `required` with `@required`.
  - Removing `late` keywords.

Comment: I have Git version control configured to this project... but however from morning I did lot of changes which I may loose if I stash it..

Answer (score 0):

environment:
sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

Add this in your pubspc.yml
Then in your terminal write
Flutter pub get , then=>
Flutter clean ,=>
Flutter run

Comment: I think you want 2.10.0 not 2.1.0.  2.1 would be quite a rollback. :)